# Merge DataFrames - Best Practice when One DF has single Column DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I find myself merging two dataframes that share a column. However, for df2 the column is really the index, while for df1 the column is just a column.

I was just wondering if there is a best practice or pythonic way to do this quickly. I am converting the index in df2 to a column but it feels like there has to be a better way:

```
new['column'] = new.index
```

Comment: merge allows specifying both `column` and `index`: `df1.merge(df2, left_on='column', right_index=True)`

Comment: This is depends on what you want in the output , can you show us ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is more like a `map`.

```
df1['new']=df1['column'].map(df2['v'])
```